# Why modeling image's pixel with char instead of unsigned int?

Tags: c, image-processing, color-space

I study different image processing project (in C\C++) to help me build *a ColorGrading App*. Including *OpenColorIO*, it seems that using char/unsigned char is part of the standard for saving image's pixels to memory.

Why using **unsigned char** instead of a more precise **(long) unsigned int** ? And how to **gain precision while using char** ? (incase I want to preserve the color depth of my image in  BT. 2020, for example)

thanks

Comment: Please clarify what you are asking, with example code. Integer variables don't have "precision": they are exact representations of natural numbers. What they have is *range*.

Comment: Many common image formats only use 8 bits/sample, e.g. JPEG, TGA, BMP, GIF. A few support 16 bits/sample, such as PNG and TIFF. And only very few support 32 or 64 bits/sample, such as TIFF and OpenEXR.

Comment: I don't start any coding, just get as much info to build a strong fondation. By "precise", I mean the range available between each step to having more shade/nuance in color. If I want to change my colors from the sRGB  colorspace to BT. 2020, Do I have to keep this 255 range that "char" give me ?

Comment: And yes, I seek to support 32 and 64bits/sample in order to import images (from RED's camera, for example), process it in the right color-space (not sRGB) and save it in OpenEXR with the same 32 or 64bits/sample on every pixels.

Comment: The very little image processing I've done used formats where each *channel* (red, green, blue, alpha) was represented using an `unsigned char`, so the overall pixel value was (typically) 32 bits wide.  Is that what you're seeing?

Comment: The RED camera uses 16 bits per sample, not 32 or 64. You should use `uint16` (or `unsigned short`) to represent these images. You can cast to float and do your computations in floating-point arithmetic if you like, nothing stopping you from doing so. But data loaded and saved should be 16 bits per sample.